# How to make operators work from the left of the object?

Tags: c++

This feels like too basic a question to not have asked already so if it's already out there I'd accept the link as the answer or delete this post if you fellas see fit, personally I couldn't find it anywhere at least so perhaps this'll be useful to others...

So yeah, like it's said in the title, how do I make operators that'd let me work from the left side of the object? f.e:

```
++obj
variable * obj
```

etc

If I wanted to work on the right side of that 'obj' I'd make something like

```
obj operator*(const variable &t){...} //for obj * variable operation
```

intuitively I tried

```
obj *operator(const variable &t){...} //for variable * obj operation(?)
```

to make it work the other way around but of course, that didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: Make it a free function, then just switch the arguments around. `obj operator*(const variable &t, const obj& o)`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "work on the left of the object", with some valid code if possible.

Comment: Implement it as a friend function and if your class has a non-explicit constructor which takes the type, it will work. Eg `5 * myobj` will work if `T operator*(const T& l, const T& r)` is a friend function and there is `T(int)` constructor.

Comment: Pretty much a combo of both what Ramyabel and Neil said and you have  your answer: friend obj operator*(const variable &t, const obj& obj_on_the_right){...} and friend obj operator*(const obj& obj_on_the_left, const variable &t){...}
(on the left/right is relative to the operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ummm you cannot do that. I mean, choose which side the operator works on. It is defined by the standard. The operators in c++ do not have sides they operate on. All are different operators. The operator you overload is defined by the signature.

The "side" has meaning only for the unary operators anyway. For binary operators it is either a member function called on the left operand, with right operand passed as an argument, or a free standing function.

The case that "allows definition of the side" is `++` and `--`. And it is a special case. `++c` and `c++` are actually two different operators in terms of language -- pre- and post- incrementation. The differentiation between realized by a "bogus" parameter in the overload: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec.

There are other unary operators too, and you cannot choose side E.g: `!`, `~`, there are no suitable overloads defined for "right side" cases.

Other disambiguation is also done via parameters. `*` used for both, member access and arithmetic operation. The operator which you overload is defined by number of parameters.

`T T::operator*(const T2 &b) const;` is artithmetic one, and `R& T::operator*();` is member access.

Here you can find rules for all operators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

Aaand since its c++ you can abuse it. Unrecommended though.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload function and make that function friend of the class.

```
variable operator*(const variable &, const variable *);

class variable {
    friend variable operator*(const variable &, const variable *);
};
```